# Random State in Matlab Cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

I have got stuck in doing crossvalidation in svm in matlab.

I wanted to  generate 5 fold stratified cross-validation and want  to reset the random number generator at each run in order to be sure  that I select always the same samples in the folds .Don't want to train on different samples as  I wish to tune my svm parameters .

Whats the variable that can be used for doing so in Matlab or in lib svm?

I found a relevant variable in python  called random_state : None, int or RandomState
If I set random state to none I wll get the same set of data so that I could fine tune my svm parameters.
Is there a similar process in  matlab?

Link: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.cross_vali
dation.KFold

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Matlab function crossvalind: 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html
Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the input.. I was looking for a variable similar to randomstate variable in python...

Comment: Is there a variable similar to random state(as in python crossvalidation) that I can use in crossvalidation in matlab?

Comment: I don't know that python function, sorry. I thought this one could solve the problem you described

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on what release of MATLAB you are using, but in relatively current releases you can issue this command:

```
rng default
```

If you want more specific control than that, try "help rng" for more information.